# Defining event with field working like Handled

Tags: c#, events

I my class I have an event with arguments containing boolean field Prevent and a default function doing some stuff if Prevent == false. I want user of my class to be able to prevent default function from doing stuff by setting Prevent = true in function listening to event. But it turned out that default function is invoked first, with Prevent = true, and then the user-defined function changes the value of the field. Is there any way of changing order of function invokation? Or any other approach which can give me the same results? I've done it by defining Func field used to check if default function should do its things and user can modify the field providing own function. It works, but I don't like the fact that 2 separate functions are needed, one to do stuff when event fires and one to prevent default behaviour.

Some of the code:

```
public Func<int, int, bool> PreventFunc = new Func<int,int,bool>( (x,y) => {return false;});

public struct MyEventArgs
{ 
     int x; 
     int y; 
     bool Prevent;
     public MyEventArgs (int i, int j, bool prev) { /*assignments*/ }
}
public delegate void MyEventDelegate(object sender, MyEventArgs e);
public event MyEventDelegate MyEvent = DefaultBehaviourFunction;

void DefaultBehaviourFunction (object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Prevent == true) return;
    //do stuff
}
```

And when invoking an event

```
MyEvent.Invoke(sender, new MyEventArgs(i, j, PreventFunc(i,j)));
```

I want it to work without the PreventFunc, like that:

```
MyEvent += Func;
void Func (object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{ 
     if (e.x == 1) e.Prevent = true;
     //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Please show code what u tried so far

Comment: @DevT Added code to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish what you are asking for literally, by getting the invocation list from the event delegate field, reversing the order, and invoking each target individually. But that would be an abuse of the event pattern, as well as simply being unwieldy.

Instead, you should implement this the way that other classes do: have the method that *raises* the event be the one that checks the `Prevent` value, not some other handler.

For example:

```
private void OnMyEvent(int i, int j, bool prevent)
{
    MyEventDelegate handler = MyEvent;
    MyEventArgs e = new MyEventArgs(i, j, prevent);

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }

    if (e.Prevent)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Member of same class, and we already know Prevent is false,
    // so just need to pass i and j.
    DefaultBehaviourFunction(i, j);
}
```

then instead of invoking the event handlers directly with `MyEvent.Invoke()` you'd call the `OnMyEvent()` method instead.